# Easy way to migrate from google code to assembla (SVN)

Tags: svn, version-control

Is there a easy way on Windows to migrate my google code SVN to assembla? 
I want to keep history

Can't get `svnsync` working like I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svnsync **require** hook on receiver's side, Assembla haven't subversion hooks at all (or only "user-defined", can't recall from  memory)

1. Export dump in Google Code (haven't projects, can't check) OR create **local RO-copy** with svnsync and dump **this** copy
2. Import dump in Assembla interface to SVN-repo

Comment: That's the problem, Google Code doesn't give a option to 'dump' your repo. Any command line on how to make the local RO-copy ?

Comment: http://creekcodes.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-svnsync-on-windows.html or http://www.svnsite.com/content/page/svnsync  `TortoiseSVN\bin>svnsync help` in common